# Excel VBA ODBC Connection Query Parameters

Tags: excel, win32ole, vba

I'd like to be able to access an Excel External ODBCConnection Query Parameters using VBA.

The Connection definition window showing the connection query (command text) is also showing a Parameters... button. Clicking on it shows the "Parameters" window.

Is it possible to access the Parameter attributes, namely that of the "Get value from the following cell"?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think I got an answer. According to [Microsoft's Query Table documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837414.aspx)

> If you import data using the user interface, data from a Web query or a text query is imported as a QueryTable object, while all other external data is imported as a ListObject object.

I can't access QueryTable from the ODBCConnection object - however - a ListObject can be accessed from the Worksheet, that ListObject contains QueryTable, which in turn contains the Parameters object containing a list of all Parameters

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(1).QueryTable.Parameters
```

parameter SourceRange will return a Range (if the Parameter type is xlRange) - setting or changing the SourceRange however is done by setting the whole Parameter again:

```
param.SetParam xlRange, Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
```

Comment: Its posible to get the format of the cells which have the parameters ? =(

Comment: You can't imagine how I needed this solution for months. Thank you for saving me!